# Openssl query about usage

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to use OpenSSL in my application, and achieve a secure connection.

At first I tried:

1. create ssl struct
2. create socketbio for the tcp socket
3. create a sslbio
4. set socketbio to SSL strcut
5. `SSL_accept(ssl)`
6. `BIO_push(ssl, socketbio)`

This cause handshake to happen successfully, but application data wasn't properly decrypted.

Then I tweaked a little, and relaced 6 with

```
(new) BIO_ctrl(sslbio, SET_SSL, ssl)
```

and things worked fine.

I Wanted to know, what's wrong with previous approach, and what's causing the new apprach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer the question without knowing why you think `BIO_push` is all you need to do.  At any rate, you shouldn't call `BIO_ctrl` directly.  You should use the high-level wrapper `BIO_set_ssl` defined in `bio.h`:

```
#define BIO_set_ssl(b,ssl,c)    BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_SET_SSL,c,(char *)ssl)
```

This macro sets the ssl member of the BIO object as you can see in `bio_ssl.c`:

```
    case BIO_C_SET_SSL:
            if (ssl != NULL)
                    ssl_free(b);
            b->shutdown=(int)num;
            ssl=(SSL *)ptr;
            ((BIO_SSL *)b->ptr)->ssl=ssl;
            bio=SSL_get_rbio(ssl);
            if (bio != NULL)
                    {
                    if (b->next_bio != NULL)
                            BIO_push(bio,b->next_bio);
                    b->next_bio=bio;
                    CRYPTO_add(&bio->references,1,CRYPTO_LOCK_BIO);
                    }
            b->init=1;
            break;
```

The important step in this function is not the `BIO_push`, but rather is where it sets the ssl pointer in the `BIO_SSL` object to your active SSL context, i.e., `((BIO_SSL *)b->ptr)->ssl=ssl;`.

Comment: thnx mate for explaining. Yes, ididn't use the ctrl direct;y but set_ssl as you mentioned above.